# Creating a List of Maps from a List using java stream

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of Students that I want to convert to a List of Maps with each map containing specifc student data.

The Student Object:

```
class Student {
  String name;
  String age;

  String getName() {
    return name;
  }
}
```

I have a list of Students that I want to convert to a list of maps that should look like the following:

```
[
  { name: "Mike",
    age: "14"
  }, 
  { name: "Jack",
    age: "10"
  }, 
  { name: "John",
    age: "16"
  },
  { name: "Paul",
    age: "12"
  } 
]
```

Is there a way to convert `List<Student>` into `List<Map<String, String>>` ? The keys of each map should be name & age.

Comment: you can take reference from https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/

Comment: Note : it seems that you actually want to convert your objects to JSON. There are libraries intended for that such as Jackson.

Comment: Indeed I want the output as JSON. But I'm bound to specific rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean :

```
List<Student> listStudent = new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String, String>> result = listStudent.stream()
        .map(student -> {
            return new HashMap<String, String>() {
                {
                    put("age", student.getAge());
                    put("name", student.getName());
                }
            };
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

For example if you have :

```
List<Student> listStudent = new ArrayList<>(
        Arrays.asList(
                new Student("Mike", "14"),
                new Student("Jack", "10"),
                new Student("John", "16"),
                new Student("Paul", "12")
        ));
```

The result should look like this :

```
[{name=Mike, age=14}, {name=Jack, age=10}, {name=John, age=16}, {name=Paul, age=12}]
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Java-9 solution using `Map.of`:

```
myList.stream()
      .map(s -> Map.of("name", s.getName(), "age", s.getAge()))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```